# Why browser console log giving me error "Datatable is not a function"?

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

I'm using datatable in my code. In my webpage there is one link when I click that the datatable will display, Upto this my code is working fine, but it was not responsive I also added required datatable script in my code, but when I saw the console log it was showing the error that the datatable is not a function. I'm using laravel and below are the datatable link I have added.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#exam-result-table').DataTable();
});

$('#show-results').click(function(event) {     
   //alert('hiiii');   
        $.ajax({
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
                type: 'POST',
                url: ExamResults,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
        error: function(data){

          },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("success");
          },
        })
        .done(function (msg) {
            $("#main-exam").empty();
            $('#main-exam').append(msg);
            $('#exam-result-table').DataTable();
        });
});
```

Datatable is showing but I didn't find the cause why console log giving error and why my datatable is not responsive.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
>   at Object.error (exam_homepage.js:166)
>   at u (app.js:3)
>   at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (app.js:3)
>   at r (app.js:4)
>   at XMLHttpRequest. (app.js:4)
>   at Object.send (app.js:4)
>   at Function.ajax (app.js:4)
>   at HTMLSpanElement. (exam_homepage.js:155)
>   at HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3074)
>   at HTMLSpanElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:2750)

Comment: How did you add the datatable script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probebly are requiring the wrong version of jQuery. 
try requiring the dataTable version with jQuery included or requre jQuery 3 before dataTable.

you can create/download your dataTable here:
https://datatables.net/download/index

for example. this is dataTable with jQuery 3:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

you can also do it like this(order is important):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

you should not require another jQuery on the same page.

Comment: Hi @Amirsadjad can you give a code example to clarify how this will solve the question